# How to split pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes (holding together rows) based upon a column's value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My problem is similar to split a dataframe into chunks of N rows problem, expect that the number of rows in each chunk will be different.  I have a datafame as such:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |

A and B are just whatever don't pay attention.  Column C though starts at 0 and increments with each row until it suddenly resets to 0.  So in the dataframe included the first 3 rows are a new dataframe, then the next 5 are a second new dataframe, and this continues as my dataframe adds more and more rows.

Comment: `df.C.eq(0).cumsum()` will give you grouping variable. Maybe that's enough instead of splitting into multiple data frames?

Comment: Well I think that is enough to get me where I want to go, thanks.  The `cumsum` function then is key.  So `df = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df['C'].eq(0).cumsum())]` would complete the task giving me back a list of dataframe with various row sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish off the question,

```
df = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df['C'].eq(0).cumsum())]
```

allows me to group all the subgroups and then with this groupby I can select each subgroups as a separate dataframe.